# No records found primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:form>
<p:outputLabel value="Primefaces Tutorial"></p:outputLabel>
<p:dataTable value="#{Liste.dizgi}" var="liste">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Agent_code"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{liste.Agent_code}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Date"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{liste.date}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</html>
```

Liste.java

```
package pro;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Liste  {

    private  List<Veri> dizgi=new ArrayList<Veri>();

    public List<Veri> getDizgi() {
        return dizgi;
    }

    public void setDizgi(List<Veri> d) {
        this.dizgi = d;
    }


    public Liste(){};
    @PostConstruct      
    void  Listele(){

         dizgi.add(new Veri("B-8821083","20150513",-1,-29));
         dizgi.add(new Veri("B-8821083","20150521",46,4.718));
         dizgi.add(new Veri("B-8821083","20150602",-5,-455));
         dizgi.add(new Veri("B-8821083","20150623",-4,-305));
         dizgi.add(new Veri("B-8821083","20150506",7,0));
         dizgi.add(new Veri("B-8821083","20150612",1,0));
         dizgi.add(new Veri("B-8821083","20150615",50,4.602));
    }
}
```

Here is the code,when I run this code.It says

> No records found.

What is the problem here?
I tried to print List two attributes as columns.It gives no error.Just no records found is showed.But actually lots of elements exist.
There is a veri class. it provides attributes such as Agent_Code and date and getter and setter methods etc.

Comment: Watch out with IDE autocomplete when importing annotations. Some annotations exist in multiple packages.

Comment: I check that actually with same imports I run another similiar code.It runs correctly.But It is strange, this one doesnt run correctly.

Comment: Use same imports as your JSF book tells you to use.